# Do I need to configure hibernate before configuring spring-data?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am a little bit lost here, my main goal is to create a MVC pattern with Spring MVC and include Spring-security with user/passwords from the database.

So far, I have Spring security and MVC running well, but I dont know how to include the database (I must use spring data in some point).

I've read the tutorials and info of the site, and it says its a layer that works with other ORM (such as hibernate). So my question is, Should I configure hibernate before Spring data?

Is there any guide on how to do it (where they use annotations only?).

Comment: There are tons of Spring Data JPA examples out there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples and you should work through some and when you get stuck, ask a specific question about the problem.  All the down votes you are getting are probably because you are not asking a specific enough question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code and they work fine, I just dont really know what they've done there... apparently there is no hibernet configured... but that is what I dont know... should hibernet be present when you use spring data or not?

Comment: Spring Data is a family of 12+ projects, one of those is Spring Data JPA, which is what it sounds like you want to learn more about.  Hibernate (note the spelling, it might help your searches) is just one implementation of JPA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API

If you want to connect to a database, hibernate with JPA is one way to do it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API  has a 9 part tutorial.

Comment: I mean http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/ for the 9 part tutorial, sorry.

Comment: i dont know why i got so many points down when it was a valid quesiton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question "do I need hibernate configured to use Spring Data JPA" is "yes" if you want Hibernate to be your JPA implentation.

So here's what the stack looks like for a typical Spring MVC + Spring Data JPA application:

```
@Controller class with @RequestMapping
 calls
@Service class
 calls
@Repository class (this annotation is optional, extend CrudRepository interface)
```

The repository you write uses an @Entity (JPA) class to access the database through Hibernate as described in this [tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/).  Spring does a great job hiding most of the setup details of Hibernate from you (you don't need a persistence.xml if you do it right).